# invisible bad guys? py game is unable to display the bad guys

Tags: python

Hello everyone I am having an issue in my game where bad guys are invisible. I am not sure where I made my error. The error I am receiving is Traceback (most recent call last):
EDIT: Please excuse my error for not showing appropriate portions.

File "c:\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages\pgzero\clock.py", line 168, in tick
    cb()
  File "gamemap1.py", line 636, in ghost_start
    ghost_map[ghost_y][ghost_x] = 49 + (room_the_player_is_in % 3)
IndexError: list assignment index out of range

```
def start_room():
    if room_the_player_is_in == 42: 
        airlock_door_frame = 0
        clock.schedule_interval(ghost_start, 0.05)
        ghost_start()

def deplete_health(penalty):
    global health, game_over
    if game_over:
        return # cant continue lossign health if dead
    health = health - penalty
    draw_health()
    if health < 1:
        end_the_game("You're dead")

def game_loop():
    global user_x, user_y, room_the_player_is_in
    global from_player_x, from_player_y
    global sprite_image 
    global selected_item, item_carrying, health 
    global player_offset_x, player_offset_y
    global frame_of_sprite, direction

    if game_over:
        return

    if frame_of_sprite > 0:
        frame_of_sprite += 1
        time.sleep(0.05)
        if frame_of_sprite == 3:
            frame_of_sprite = 0
            player_offset_x = 0
            player_offset_y = 0

# save player's current position
    old_player_x = user_x
    old_player_y = user_y

######################################################################################
  # if is standing somewhere they shouldn't, move them back.
    if room_map[user_y][user_x] not in items_player_may_stand_on or ghost_map[user_y][user_x] != 0:
        user_x = old_player_x
        user_y = old_player_y
        frame_of_sprite = 0

    if room_map[user_y][user_x] == 29: # if player on winning dsapceship start win game 
       game_completion_sequence()

    if direction == "right" and frame_of_sprite > 0:
        player_offset_x = -1 + (0.25 * frame_of_sprite)
    if direction == "left" and frame_of_sprite > 0:
        player_offset_x = 1 - (0.25 * frame_of_sprite)
    if direction == "up" and frame_of_sprite > 0:
        player_offset_y = 1 - (0.25 * frame_of_sprite)
    if direction == "down" and frame_of_sprite > 0:
        player_offset_y = -1 + (0.25 * frame_of_sprite)


###############################Show image in generated window#######################################################

def draw_image(image, y, x):
    screen.blit(
        image,
        (top_left_x + (x * ROOM_SIZE),
         top_left_y + (y * ROOM_SIZE) - image.get_height())
        )

def draw_player():
    sprite_image = SPRITE[direction][frame_of_sprite]
    draw_image(sprite_image, user_y + player_offset_y,
               user_x + player_offset_x)

def draw():
    if game_over:
        return
##############################Show image in generated window#######################################################

    # Clear the game arena area.
    box = Rect((100, 150), (800, 600))
    screen.draw.filled_rect(box, PINK)
    box = Rect ((0, 0), (800, top_left_y + (room_height - 1)*30))
    screen.surface.set_clip(box)
    floor_type = get_floor_type()

    for y in range(room_height): # Lay down floor tiles, then items on floor.
        for x in range(room_width):
            draw_image(items[floor_type][0], y, x)
            if room_map[y][x] in items_player_may_stand_on: 
                draw_image(items[room_map[y][x]][0], y, x)
            # Next line enables shadows to fall on top of objects on floor

    for y in range(room_height):
        for x in range(room_width):
            item_here = room_map[y][x]
            # Player cannot walk on 255: it marks spaces used by wide objects.
            if item_here not in items_player_may_stand_on + [265]:
                image = items[item_here][0]# no vaule in

                if (room_the_player_is_in in planet_surface 
                    and y == room_height - 1
                    and room_map[y][x] == 1) or(room_the_player_is_in not in planet_surface
                    and y == room_height - 1
                    and room_map[y][x] == 1
                    and x > 0
                    and x < room_width - 1): 
                    # Add transparent wall image in the front row.
                    image = inviso_wall[wall_transparency_frame]

                draw_image(image, y, x)
                ghost_here = ghost_map[y][x]
                if ghost_here != 0: # If there's a hazard at this position
                    draw_image(items[ghost_here][0], y, x)###issue here???
        if (user_y == y):
                draw_player()
    screen.surface.set_clip(None)

def adjust_wall_transparency():
    global wall_transparency_frame

    if (user_y == room_height - 2
        and room_map[room_height - 1][user_x] == 1
        and wall_transparency_frame < 4):  
        wall_transparency_frame += 1 # Fade wall out.

    if ((user_y < room_height - 2
            or room_map[room_height - 1][user_x] != 1)
            and wall_transparency_frame > 0):
        wall_transparency_frame -= 1 # Fade wall in.

def show_text(text_to_show, line_number):
    if game_over:
        return
    text_lines = [15, 50]



################################GAME COMPLETION SEQUANCE#############################################################################################################

def game_completion_sequence():
    global game_over 
    game_over = True
    sounds.winnerr.play(0)

    screen.draw.text("MAZE", (200, 400), color = "white",
                     fontsize = 128)
    screen.draw.text("COMPLETE", (145, 480), color = "white",
                     fontsize = 128)

    game_over = True# win the maze

def end_the_game(reason):
    global game_over
    show_text(reason, 1)
    game_over = True
    sounds.loser.play()
    screen.draw.text("GAME OVER", (80, 400), color = "white",
                     fontsize = 160)






################################BAD GUY DARA ########################################################################################################################

ghost_data = {# dictionary
    #room number: [[y, x, direction, bounce addition to direction]]
    26: [[1, 8, 2, 1], [7, 3, 4, 1]],
    27: [[1, 8, 2, 1], [7, 3, 4, 1]],
    28: [[1, 8, 2, 1], [7, 3, 4, 1]], 
    29: [[1, 8, 2, 1], [7, 3, 4, 1]],
    30: [[1, 8, 2, 1], [7, 3, 4, 1]],
    31: [[1, 8, 2, 1], [7, 3, 4, 1]],
    34: [[5, 1, 1, 1], [5, 5, 1, 2]],
    35: [[4, 4, 1, 2], [2, 5, 2, 2]],
    36: [[2, 1, 2, 2]], 
    37: [[1, 8, 2, 1], [7, 3, 4, 1]],
    38: [[1, 8, 2, 1], [7, 3, 4, 1]],
    39: [[1, 8, 2, 1], [7, 3, 4, 1]],
    40: [[3, 1, 3, -1], [6, 5, 2, 2], [7, 5, 4, 2]],
    41: [[4, 5, 2, 2], [6, 3, 4, 2], [8, 1, 2, 2]],
    44: [[2, 1, 2, 2], [4, 3, 2, 2], [6, 5, 2, 2]],
    45: [[2, 1, 2, 2], [4, 3, 2, 2], [6, 5, 2, 2]],
    46: [[2, 1, 2, 2]],
    47: [[2, 1, 2, 2], [4, 3, 2, 2], [6, 5, 2, 2]],
    48: [[1, 8, 3, 2], [8, 8, 1, 2], [3, 9, 3, 2]],
    49: [[2, 1, 2, 2], [4, 3, 2, 2], [6, 5, 2, 2]]
    }



def ghost_start():
    global current_room_ghost_list, ghost_map
    if room_the_player_is_in in ghost_data.keys():
        current_room_ghost_list = ghost_data[room_the_player_is_in]
        for ghost in current_room_ghost_list:
            ghost_y = ghost[0]
            ghost_x = ghost[1]
            ghost_map[ghost_y][ghost_x] = 49 + (room_the_player_is_in % 3)
        clock.schedule_interval(ghost_move, 0.20)

def ghost_move():
    global current_room_ghost_list, ghost_data, ghost_map, old_player_x, old_player_y

    if game_over:
        return

    for ghost in current_room_ghost_list:
        ghost_y = ghost[0]
        ghost_x = ghost[1]
        ghost_direction = ghost[2]

        old_ghost_x = ghost_x
        old_ghost_y = ghost_y
        ghost_map[old_ghost_y][old_ghost_x] = 0 

        if ghost_direction == 1: # up
            ghost_y -= 1
        if ghost_direction == 2: # right
            ghost_x += 1
        if ghost_direction == 3: # down
            ghost_y += 1
        if ghost_direction == 4: # left
            ghost_x -= 1

        ghost_should_bounce = False

        if (ghost_y == user_y and ghost_x == user_x) or (ghost_y == from_player_y and ghost_x == from_player_x and frame_of_sprite > 0):
            sounds.ouch.play()######################################################
            deplete_health(1)
            ghost_should_bounce = True

        # Stop going out of the doors
        if ghost_x == room_width: 
            ghost_should_bounce = True
            ghost_x = room_width - 1
        if ghost_x == -1: 
            ghost_should_bounce = True
            ghost_x = 0
        if ghost_y == room_height:
            ghost_should_bounce = True
            ghost_y = room_height - 1
        if ghost_y == -1:
            ghost_should_bounce = True
            ghost_y = 0

        # Stop when hazard hits scenery or another hazard.
        if room_map[ghost_y][ghost_x] not in items_player_may_stand_on or ghost_map[ghost_y][ghost_x] != 0:
            ghost_should_bounce = True

        if ghost_should_bounce:
            ghost_y = old_ghost_y # Move back to last valid position.
            ghost_x = old_ghost_x
            ghost_direction += ghost[3]
            if ghost_direction > 4:
                ghost_direction -= 4
            if ghost_direction < 1:
                ghost_direction += 4
            ghost[2] = ghost_direction

        ghost_map[ghost_y][ghost_x] = 49 + (room_the_player_is_in % 3)
        ghost[0] = ghost_y
        ghost[1] = ghost_x
```

Comment: right above that line, can you print out `ghost_y` and `ghost_x`? those should be ints that are less than the size of the ghost_map

Comment: Hmm - probably also worth printing room_width & room_height (to make sure they're correct). This smells like an off-by-one error to me.

Comment: Either way, this is very, *very* far from meeting the "minimal" part of the [mre] spec.

Comment: Please read the following help center articles attentively: [ask], [mcve].

Comment: @Charles Duffy I have edited my code to the relevant sections. please excuse me and my error.

Comment: I feel like i am missing something obvious. I have changed it to the size of my map and to the size of ghost dictionary and am still receiving the error.  The mechanics of the ghosts work however they are not "drawn".